# Можно ли запустить скрипт, как программу?

Tags: javascript

Имея javascript файл, могу ли я запустить его не в браузере? Как программу или что-то похожее. Без использования node и других ему подобных.

Comment: Правильный ответ уже отмечен. Но если вдруг javascript engine еще есть

Comment: почему же без нод? `chmod +x script.js`, первой строкой `#!/usr/bin/env node`  и вот уже пишем по-взрослому

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Windows есть встроенный интерпретатор JScript (JavaScript от Microsoft). Он есть в консольной версии (csript.exe) и GUI версии (wscript.exe). Файлы с расширением js проассоциированы с wscript.exe